# Join query on two views

Tags: java, sql

I have two views master and detail. Master view has status column and detail view has some history. I need to find out the count of history of closed case for open/pend case.

Right now I am using Java code to do this in two steps

1. First get list of open/pend.
2. Then loop on the result to get the count for closed case.

Problem is it is running very slow since step 2 query take 6sec each and if I have 20 query for pagination  from step 1 it takes 2min + run time for first query.

My SQL is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29918/12)

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.*, rownum row_num FROM ( 
    select vtm.user_id, vtm.provider_id, COUNT(*) OVER () RESULT_COUNT
    from VW_Master vtm
    where vtm.status = 'OPEN' or vtm.status= 'PEND')
  )a
  WHERE rownum < 21
)WHERE row_num > = 1;
```

Comment: How are you doing a pagination?

Comment: Edited with pagination code

Comment: What database are you using? Are this rownum fixed or not?

Comment: Oracle 11g. No rownum is parameterized. Changed as paging size changes.

Comment: If you are using Oracle11g why didn't you tag in your question? And you created a fiddle using MySQL which does not support windowing function? And I don't get how you relate the results from the query in your pagination. Do `explain analyze` on your query and you will know why your query is slow. BTW why do you don't use primary and foreign keys. And some indexes could makes your queries run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join your views on `event_id` like this :

```
select vtm.*, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from VW_Detail vtc 
    inner join VW_Master vtm2 on vtc.event_id = vtm2.event_id
    where vtc.user_id = vtm.user_id and vtc.provider_id = vtm.provider_id and vtm2.status = 'CLOSE'
  )
from VW_Master vtm
where vtm.status = 'OPEN' or vtm.status = 'PEND';
```

This one is doing the job and **I think** despite of the subrequest it is still more efficient than the request with the cartesian product.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Run time didn't improved significantly. Is there a way to combine two queries instead of me having to do for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the joined queries:

```
select user_id, provider_id, count(*)
from VW_Master vtm, VW_Detail vtc
where 
     vtm.user_id in 
        (select user_id from VW_Master vtm where status = 'OPEN' or status= 'PEND')
  and vtm.provider_id in 
       (select provider_id from VW_Master vtm where status = 'OPEN' or status= 'PEND')
  and vtm.status = 'CLOSE' 
  and vtm.event_id = vtc.event_id
group by user_id, provider_id;
```

I assumed you wanted that.

Comment: This one gives me count only. I need to list open/pend from master and count too for each row.

Comment: Couldn't link with my pagination query statement